# PHP find & replace with str_replace in RTF document

Tags: php, rtf, str-replace

I'm pretty sure this is a futile thing I'm shooting for. But It's still worth a try.

I'm successfully using str_replace() inside several RTF (Rich Text Format) files. Simple strings like the client's name, phone, addresses, etc....

I notice on some of the RTF's are checkboxes.  I can't imagine a way to use str_replace() with checkboxes, in the sense of replacing with a 'checked' version or unchecked version of the box.  And as I look into microsoft word, the checkboxes appear to be part of the picture tools format.  And Open Office has their version as well, it seems.

Either way, I'm not wanting to chase a dream if php cannot really find the rich text that produces the checkbox images.

Does anyone agree?  or has someone been successful with this?

I opened the RTF in a program called TEA (http://tea-editor.sourceforge.net/)

Looking around, I found 2 examples inside:

```
For Sale by Owner?
shapeType75fFlipH0fFlipV0pibFlags2fLine0fLayoutInCell1fLayoutInCell1d724799ad49a250ce6f9f6f010efdc1ad724799ad49a250ce6f9f6f010efdc1a
   Yes
shapeType75fFlipH0fFlipV0pibFlags2fLine0fLayoutInCell1fLayoutInCell1d724799ad49a250ce6f9f6f010efdc1ad724799ad49a250ce6f9f6f010efdc1a
    No
```

So, I'm seeing shapetype75.... is what creates the box, and they are both empty boxes.
I'm gonna guess I just need to create similar box that is populated, and pull my conditional code on those guys.

Comment: If you posted a sample of the text you're looking to find/replace people would be better able to answer this ...

Comment: Please show an example of the RTF markup that creates the checkboxes behind the scenes.

Comment: I'll post that above....

Comment: Please post an excerpt from the RAW RTF source, what you posted is not real RTF but something pre-parsed. That's not really useable to answer your question.

Comment: supposedly this is a class to parse RTF docs. http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1930-PHP-RTF-to-HTML-converter-with-latin-character-support.html